# disable times in date picker js

Tags: javascript, datepicker

using http://amsul.ca/pickadate.js/api/

I'm trying to do something like this with pickatime js :

```
var close_times = [{from: [0,0], to: [23,45]}];
var enable_times = [{from: [9,0], to: [17,0]}];
var overbooked_times = [{from: [14,0], to: [15,0]}];
booking_form.timepicker.set( 'disable', close_times  );
booking_form.timepicker.set( 'enable', enable_times  );
booking_form.timepicker.set( 'disable', overbooked_times  );
```

This is for a booking system where there are standard opening hours during which one can book. But occasionally I need to close slots that are fully booked.

I can't get the above code to work-  overbooked_times are never disabled in the picker; is there something I'm missing?

Answer (score 0):

I've never used this library. But i've just checked the docs.

http://amsul.ca/pickadate.js/api/#method-set-disable-enable

In their examples i found that if you use `disable` `enable` `disable`, the enabled times will not clear.

Check the **disable/enable times, ranges of times example**. if you use the buttons in this order: disable, enable, disable, the enabled times will not clear.

I think that you either have to clear the enabled times somehow before disabling. Or maybe use only one function with clear.

By default they're all enabled why do you: disable, enable, disable?

You might just need something like:

```
var disabled_times = [{from: [0,0], to: [9,0]}, {from: [17,0], to: [24,45]}];
var overbooked_times = [{from: [14,0], to: [15,0]}];
// added this for as an example in case you've got more overbooked times than this... which might be the case
for(var i=0, i < overbooked_times.length; i++){
    disabled_times.push(overbooked_times[i]);
}
booking_form.timepicker.set( 'disable', disabled_times  );
```

Of course if you might refresh this values you will need to:

```
booking_form.timepicker.stop().start().set( 'disable', disabled_times  );
```